# Infection with virus just by extracting an archive (zip/rar/iso)?

Tags: virus, iso-image, zip, rar

is my Computer compromised with a Virus, when extracting an archive like zip/rar/iso with WinRAR, which contains an (Virus-)downloader.exe even when i didn't start the executable? and the Anti Virus software interfered?

sorry for my bad English
kind regards

Comment: Are you asking if it actually happened or if it's possible.

Comment: yes, if its actually happened! even though i didn't clicked on the .exe file

Comment: you are sure the infection came from the archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A computer virus is a computer program.  A computer program is a series of instructions that the computer should follow.

In theory, a virus is not a problem unless a computer is following the instructions.  It is like a book that contains dangerous instructions, like how to make a bomb.  As long as it sites on the bookshelf, it's not really causing problems.  Maybe it is potentially dangerous, because somebody could pull the book off of the shelf and start using it.  However, just sitting there, the book probably has no effect.

In theory, extracting a virus from an archive should not cause the instructions to be followed.  You should be able to extract all sorts of dangerous data, but as long as it isn't used, or as long as it is only used in good ways, this should be safe to do without causing problems.

Now, you may have noticed that I keep saying "in theory".  There is one possible problem with this theory.  Presumably you're not extracting the data manually.  Instead, you're using a piece of computer software (like the superior 7-Zip, or like WiZ or WinRAR) to extract the data.  If the program that you're using has a bug, it may do a wrong action.  If someone discovers that bug, they might be able to create an archive file that results in the the bug being used to cause the extracting software to do something undesirable, like starting to run code.

Another example of this is that graphics files cannot harm a computer, in theory.  Like any other data, the data can be carefully handled by skilled people and not cause trouble.  However, data combined with insecure software can lead to a computer performing undesirable instructions.  For example, [MS04-028](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms04-028) documents some Microsoft software that could be vulnerable to certain JPEG files.

So, in theory, you should be able to extract files safely.  In reality, there is a possibility of problems if someone can manage to use a known flaw in whatever software you use.